# Unable to show and hide ProgressBar during download in action

Tags: java, android

I've created an app which by clicking on a list Item, downloads an image from the `Internet` on a button click (also it places the `url` on to the `EditText` for user to see what the `url` is).

Initially I'm setting the `ProgressBar` and `TextView` (indicating `Loading....`) in a hide mode. But as the download starts, I would like to bring both `TextView` and `ProgressBar` on to the UI and once the download completes, would like to make both of them invisible.

There is NO error message on the `LogCat` to post. I believe I'm missing something which is tricky :). Let me know if any additional information is required. Thanks SO in advance.

Below is the `XML`: for `LinearLayout` which should be `ON/OFF`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/downloadImage"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loadingMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading....."
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And below is the `Java` file:

```
public class DownloadImages_HandlerMainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
private EditText editText;
private ListView listView;
private TextView textView;
private String[] listOfImages;
private Button downloadImage;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private LinearLayout loadingSection = null;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.downloadimages_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.downloadURL);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.urlList);
    downloadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadImage);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    listOfImages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imageURLs);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    handler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    editText.setText(listOfImages[position]);
}

public void downloadImage(View view) {
    String url = editText.getText().toString();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new DownloadImagesThread(url));
    myThread.start();
}

public boolean downloadImageUsingThreads(String url) {

    boolean successful = false;
    URL downloadURL = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    File file = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {
        downloadURL = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
                + "/" + Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment());
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            //Log.d("BRK0018", " " + read);
            successful = true;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);
    } finally {
        // This is the HANDLER INSTANCE in place of thread
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadingSection.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Making the ProgressBar INVISIBLE

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);                  
                }
            }
        });
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);
            }
        }
    }
    return successful;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class DownloadImagesThread implements Runnable {
    private String url;
    public DownloadImagesThread(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    // This is the HANDLER INSTANCE in place of thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    loadingSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Making the ProgressBar VISIBLE

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);
                }
            }
        });
        downloadImageUsingThreads(url);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `loadingSection` which is **`null`**. And since you change its visibility in `try/catch` block, the app doesn't crash. Initialize the layout in `onCreate()`:

```
loadingSection = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingSection);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you call

```
  handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        loadingSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BRK0018", " " + e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Handler.class runs above code in UI thread. 
You must not call `Thread.sleep(1000)` in UI thread.
(but anyway remember that  `loadingSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` must be called in UI thread)

Fix it. And whether it helps or not write me.

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000); i've put to see if that works but before that I didn't have that Line of code. Tested that but didn't help. Please have a look at my latest post above and comment - Thanks.